# How to use couchdb reduce for a map that has multiple elements for values

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere, so maybe this is not allowed but I can't find any couchdb info that confirms this.  Here is a scenario:

Suppose for a map function, within Futon, I'm emitting a value for a key, ex. K(1).  This value is comprised of two separate floating point numbers A(1) and B(1) for key K(1).  I would like to have a reduction perform the sample average of the ratio A(N)/B(N) over all K(N) from 1 to N.  The issue I'm always running into in the reduce function is for the "values" parameter.  Each key is associated with a value pair of (A,B), but I can't break out the A, B floating numbers from "values".

I can't seem to find any examples on how to do this.  I've already tried accessing multi-level javascript arrays for "values" but it doesn't work, below is my map function.

```js
function(doc) {
  if(doc['Reqt.ID']) {
    doc['Reqt.ID'].forEach(function(reqt) {
      row_index=doc['Reqt.ID'].indexOf(reqt);
      if(doc.Resource[row_index]=="Joe Smith")
          emit({rid:reqt},{acthrs:doc['Spent.Hours']  [row_index],esthrs:doc['Estimate.Total.Hours'][row_index]});
      });
  }  
}
```

I can get this to work (i.e. avg ratio) if I just produce a map that emits a single element value of A/B within the map function, but I'm curious about this case of multiple value elements.

How is this generally done within the Futon reduce function?

I've already tried various JSON Javascript notations such as `values[key index].esthrs[0]` within a for loop of the keys, but none of my combinations work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Seems like a simple question, but what do you mean by this `K(1)` notation? Are you sure this code example makes sense? `doc['Reqt.ID']` is really a list?

Comment: Have you tried emitting a single numeric value for each emitted row and applying the `_stats` reduce to the view?

Comment: The K(1) notation is just pointing to a specific instance of a key value, whose instance is numbered 1.  It's associated values are A(1) and B(1),  just didn't use LaTeX, too lazy.  Also, the above map function is fine, as it produces a view as expected. It is the reduce function that I'm having trouble with. With respect to your 2nd comment, yes, emitting just a single value is fine as well, again no issues there.  I'm having a specific problem in specifying the correct JSON Javascript notation within Futon reduce function(keys, values, rereduce) for compounded "values"

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but its usually a good idea to use *anything but* a json object as the key part of your view; erlang is able to preserve key order, and defines a meaningful, stable sorting on hash tables, but most other languages don't, most notably javascript, which you seen to be using in views.  objects are fine in the values, but in the keys its a pain.  Consider using arrays: `emit([this, that], {other: stuff})`

Comment: Thank you. I find it interesting that the general pattern for reduce  of an emit in Futon doesn't appear to allow for a pattern that looks like -> emit(key,{value1,value2,...valueN}) where valueN is a JSON object.  At least, I can't seem to find any examples.  All your alternative and others that involve emitting a single value object works fine, but am a little surprised about how this particular case of using compounded values is difficult to support in a reduce, possibly there is no benefit of having one map function for numerous  reduce functions, isn't more efficient to have 1 map B-tree?

Comment: To be clear, I can create a reduce that will do what I want in this case by sending a simple array object as a value in the emit or any other single value object, but I'm just doggedly going after some examples on supporting compounded values within emit as described above, please leave your bitcoin address if you desire and I'll send a little your way on answers that show a working example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could approach this;  first, my reccomendation, is to change your map function to make it more of a "keys are keys and values are values", which in your particular case probably means, since you have two "values" you'd like to work with, `Spent.Hours` and `Estimate.Total.Hours`, you'll need two views; although you can cheat a little, but issuing multiple `emit()`'s per row, in the same view, for example:

```
emit(["Spent.Hours", reqt], doc['Spent.Hours'][row_index]);
emit(["Estimate.Total.Hours", reqt], doc['Estimate.Total.Hours'][row_index]);
```

with that approach, you can just use the predefined `_stats` reduce function.

alternatively, you can define a "smart" stats function, which can do the statistics for more elaborate documents.

The standard `_stats` function provides count, sum, average and standard  deviation.  the algorithm it uses is to take the sum of the value, the sum of the value squared, and the count of values; from just these, average and standard deviation can be calculated (and is embedded, for convenience in the reduced view)

roughly, that might look like:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
    function getstats(seq, getter) {
        var c, s, s2 = 0, 0, 0;
        values.forEach(function (row) {
            var value = getter(row);
            if (rereduce) {
                c += value.count;
                s += value.sum;
                s2 += value.sumsq;
            } else {
                c += 1;
                s += value;
                s2 += value * value;
            }
        return {
            count: c,
            sum: s,
            sumsq: s2,
            average: s / c,
            stddev: Math.sqrt(c * s2 - s1) / c
        };
    }
    return {esthrs: getstats(function(x){return x.esthrs}),
            acthrs: getstats(function(x){return x.acthrs})};
}
```

---